# Asynchronous data retrieval and caching

Tags: javascript, caching, d3.js

I want to periodically rerun some method that depends on data retrieved from the server*. However, I also want to cache that data and only hit the server once.

If it was jQuery, I would do something like

```
function draw() {
  var data = undefined;

  // Pre-data retrieval code
  var foo, bar, alpha, beta, gamma, etc.
  ...

  if (data == undefined) {
    $.ajax({
      ...
      async: false, // IMPORTANT PART
      success: function(data) {
         data = processData(data);
      }
    });
  }

  doSomethingComplex(data);

  // Defined within to inherit scope
  // i.e., don't want to pass in foo, bar, alpha, beta, gamma, etc.
  function doSomethingComplex() {...}
}
```

However, d3's XHR functions seem to hardcode the `async` parameter to true. So I find myself doing something like

```
if (data != undefined) doSomething(data);
else {
  d3.json(..., function(data) {
    data = processData(data);
    doSomething(data);
    }
}
```

1) What other designs are there for caching and deciding whether to make an AJAX call? Specifically in d3.

2) Defining `doSomethingComplex` within the `draw` function (to avoid passing in a lot of parameters) seems lazy. Any advantages to passing in each variable?

**My specific case is redrawing a d3 bar chart on window resize (I did not like how `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` handled text resizing). I'll gladly hear other suggestions to redrawing on resize, but am interested in suggestions to the above design*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is the better way. Making an Ajax call with `sync: true` makes it **synchronous** and defeats the whole purpose of making an AJAX (remember what the **A** stands for in AJAX) call.

As far as calling `doSomethingComplex` within draw is good or bad is kind of tricky thing to answer without looking at a holistic level at your entire design. On the surface, it violates [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), but then, with JavaScript, sometimes doing so can make the overall code flow logical and easier to follow. I tend to trade in dogmatism in favor of pragmatism when it makes sense.

I would say try to refactor the code so that it doesn't need to call `doSomethingComplex` within draw and see if that makes more sense. In general, the less tasks a single function does, the easier it is to test and maintain the code, not to forget the less chance of that being buggy.

To reduce the number of variables required to pass, you can always wrap them in a single object:

```
var state = {
 foo: ...,
 bar: ...
 ...
};

doSomethingComplex(state);
```

by passing state like this, you'll avoid closure related side effects as well. Not saying closures are always bad, but if you can manage to have one less thing to worry about, why not do that?

Again, all of this depends on how things fit in the larger picture and use these points a guiding light. There is no silver bullet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should feel uncomfortable about using closures.
by the way, I like your second code example more than the first with the "sync" code. It may
seem more straight to someone who is not used to closures, but this is only a matter of getting accustomed.

is there something beside "taste" that makes you feel uncomfortable about the second example?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @lebolo asks if "Is there a better overall design for caching and deciding whether to make an AJAX call?". thus my answer - your design is perfectly ok.